# Is the latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image available on Docker Hub trusted/signed or not?

Tags: 18.04, docker

I observed that 26 Nov 2020 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image is last trusted/signed image on Docker Hub, is this true?

Here trusted means we are focusing on "Docker Content Trust".

When we are trying to pull Ubuntu:18.04 image with DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 (DCT enabled),we are getting image that is created 8 months ago.
However if we set DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=0 , we get image that is created 15 days ago (created 14th July 2021 ).
Based on the above observations , we stated that 26th Nov 2020 (created 8 month ago) Ubuntu 18.04 image is the last signed/trusted image. Could you please confirm once that latest image (14th July 2021)is pushed on Docker Hub is signed/trusted or not?

Comment: I've edited to focus on the main question, and not 3-4 additional questions.

Comment: I don't understand your tags; this relates to the Xubuntu 18.04 desktop? but also docker, and to the Ubuntu SSO service Ubuntu-ONE.  You mention Ubuntu base image; which is different to the ISOs provided by the Xubuntu team - so please clarify your question & how the tags related (Ubuntu's SSO service Ubuntu-ONE is operated by Canonical)

Comment: There were no tags associated with questions and we had to select at-least 5 tags ..I selected those that are related to Ubuntu

Comment: You don't have to select 5 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Docker images are [official images](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) released directly by Canonical. And it's correct that the 26 Nov 2020 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image is the most recent signed image.

It seems signed images are updated on a less regular basis than unsigned, so you have to choose either signed with DCT or latest - you can't have both.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am here referring to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image available on Docker Hub at https://hub.docker.com/layers/ubuntu/library/ubuntu/18.04/images/sha256-e54a1aafac9c4533cc1ef8389ca472248d24671340fe64c0b081513998d32616?context=explore

Comment: When we are trying to pull Ubuntu:18.04 image with DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1 (DCT enabled),we are getting image that is created 8 months ago.
However if we set DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=0 , we get image that is created 15 days ago (created 14th July 2021 ).
Based on the above observations , We stated that 26th Nov 2020 (created 8 month ago) Ubuntu 18.04 image is the last signed/trusted image.
Could you please confirm once that  latest image (14th July 2021)that is pushed on Docker Hub is signed/trusted or not?